# What is the best way to update only specific items in an array after certain times?

Tags: computer-science, abstraction

I'm asking what the best idea is to update a set of data after a certain time.

I have an Array of Objects, each with its own timestamp and other variables. In, for example, 5 minutes a variable of one of the objects has to automatically be changed, and for another item it could be in 8 minutes, etc.

My current solution is to have a timer that runs a function every 15 seconds to compare the timestamp of **every** Object in the Array to the current timestamp, but this can't be efficient especially as the Array grows in size.

I don't care about the programming specifics, but what would be the abstract idea of how to implement this?

Comment: This seems much to broad for there to be any good answer. Which language? How do you determine when each has to change? Do you know beforehand which ones will change? Most of all, what determines which is "best"? *"I don't care about the programming specifics"* - StackOverflow requires posts to be *as specific as possible*, so I'm not sure this question is really suited for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a priority queue. Each item's priority is the clock time at which its next update is due. It's O(log(N)) time to remove the next item from the queue and O(log(N)) time to reinsert the item with its next due time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashMap to store the object using the object timestamp as the key. This would allow you to access the object with O(1) time complexity.